# ItemsControl button click command

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls, wpf-controls, itemscontrol

I need some quick help which is a road blocker for me now. I have `Button` in `ItemsControl` and I need to perform some task on Button click. I tried adding `Command` to `Button` in I`temsControl` `DataTemplate` but its not working. Can anyone suggest how to proceed further.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:key="mytask">
        <TextBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=PriorNote}" Grid.ColumnSpan="7"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,5" Width="505" Foreground="Black"/>
        <StatusBarItem Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="8" Margin="8,7,7,8" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Button x:Name="DetailsButton" Command="{Binding CommandDetailsButtonClick}">
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ListStpRules}" 
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myTaskTemplate}" Background="Black"
                  AlternationCount="2" >
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

and in ViewModel I have implemented code for Command. And its not working. Please suggest any solution for me to proceed further

Answer (score 24):

The `DataContext` of each item in your `ItemsControl` is the item in the collection the `ItemsControl` is bound to. If this item contains the `Command`, your code should work fine.

However, this is not usually the case. Typically there is a ViewModel containing an `ObservableCollection` of items for the `ItemsContro`l, and the Command to execute. If this is your case, you'll need to change the `Source` of your binding so it looks for the command in `ItemsControl.DataContext`, not `ItemsControl.Item[X]`

```
<Button Command="{Binding 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, 
    Path=DataContext.MyCommand}" />
```

Comment: Adding to Rachel's good answer, if you want to pass item as parameter, use CommandParameter="{Binding}"...

Comment: +1 This worked perfectly for me! I actually needed to bind to a `Command` in the View and not ViewModel, so I used: `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=MyCommand}` instead =]

Answer (score 0):

If your ViewModel has a property of type `ICommand` you can bind the `Button`'s `Command` property to that:

XAML:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:FooViewModel}">
   <Button Content="Click!" Command="{Binding Path=DoBarCommand}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

C#:

```
public sealed class FooViewModel
{
  public ICommand DoBarCommand
  {
    get;
    private set;
  }
  //...
  public FooViewModel()
  {
     this.DoBarCommand = new DelegateCommand(this.CanDoBar, this.DoBar);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Implement a class similar to `RelayCommand` in the above article. Would make your further MVVM coding easier. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess. Is `CommandDetailsButtonClick` defined in a ViewModel, which is `DataContext` of your UserControl (the one with ListStpRules property)?

`DataContext` of button in `ItemTemplate` is an item from `ListStpRules`, and if you command is not there then binding won't find it.

You can check diagnostic messages from wpf in Output window while debugging your application. It writes there if it can not resolve binding.